# ctrl+c interrupt signal handler in c++ stops working when embedded python execution starts

Tags: python, c++

I am executing a detached thread from my c++ program. The thread runs a python embedded program for each execution. Until the python execution starts with the below statement :

```
PyObject_Call( pAddFn , pPosArgs , pKywdArgs )
```

the signal handler works.
Once the python script execution starts, the c++ signal handler does not work. Even after the execution finishes the handler does not work.